# PDFRenderer gives error while opening an encrypted pdf

Tags: java, pdfrenderer

I am trying to open an encrypted pdf file in java program through PDFRenderer library. When compiling the code gives error for the PDFPassword class. Here is the part of my code.

```
    RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(new File(filename), "r");
    FileChannel fc = raf.getChannel();
    ByteBuffer buf = fc.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, fc.size());
    String password = "58e72df9-0";
    try{
    PDFPassword pass = new PDFPassword(password);
    //System.out.println(PDFPassword.nonNullPassword(pass));
    PDFFile pdffile = new PDFFile(buf, pass);
```

And the error i am getting is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at com.sun.pdfview.decrypt.PDFPassword$PDFDocEncodingByteGenerator.createCharsetEncoder(PDFPassword.java:256)
at com.sun.pdfview.decrypt.PDFPassword$CharsetEncoderGenerator.generateBytes(PDFPassword.java:222)
at com.sun.pdfview.decrypt.PDFPassword.generatePossiblePasswordBytes(PDFPassword.java:167)
at com.sun.pdfview.decrypt.PDFPassword.getPasswordBytes(PDFPassword.java:111)
at com.sun.pdfview.decrypt.StandardDecrypter.<init>(StandardDecrypter.java:159)
at com.sun.pdfview.decrypt.PDFDecrypterFactory.createStandardDecrypter(PDFDecrypterFactory.java:316)
at com.sun.pdfview.decrypt.PDFDecrypterFactory.createDecryptor(PDFDecrypterFactory.java:99)
at com.sun.pdfview.PDFFile.readTrailer(PDFFile.java:1051)
at com.sun.pdfview.PDFFile.parseFile(PDFFile.java:1175)
at com.sun.pdfview.PDFFile.<init>(PDFFile.java:126)
at pdfview.pdfView.main(PdfView.java:49)
    Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -128
at com.sun.pdfview.PDFDocCharsetEncoder.<clinit>(PDFDocCharsetEncoder.java:68)
... 11 more
```

Comment: Provide the code around the line 49 of PdfView.java for more details?

Comment: the above code snippet is around line 49 only with line 49 being the last line of the given code.

Comment: Works for me with my own encrypted pdf file.  Maybe it is the file you have?  I used AES 128 bit encryption on my pdf file.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your problem but also:

if you use [this](https://github.com/jblough/Android-Pdf-Viewer-Library) library it has
crypto bug which is recursively call itselfs.

i have crypto problem which is stackoverflow.I found the problem and it solve stackoverflow problem.
Change CryptoCipher class like [this](https://github.com/jblough/Android-Pdf-Viewer-Library/issues/8)

maybe this solve your problem

Comment: The problem is only when the password contains special characters such as - / @ # $ and so on . For normal password alpha numeric it doesn't crash

Comment: No. I didnt . I will try